# Auto implemented properties in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to continue to utilise auto-implemented properties while still raising a change event, such as **INotifyPropertyChanged**, when Set is called?

Instead of:

```
private string _value;
public string Value
{
  get 
  { 
    return this._value;
  }
  set
  {
    this._value = value;
    this.ValueChanged(this,EventArgs.Empty);
  }
}
```

Can I just do:

```
public string Value 
{ 
   get; 
   set 
   { 
     this.ValueChanged(this,EventArgs.Empty); 
   }
}
```

Although the setter looks wrong, is it possible to do this without filling my class with backing-store variables?

UPDATE: Looks like there is no standard solution to my lazy objective, I think that the best solution is to use CodeRush or Resharper to generate all my backing stores for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this.  The specification for automatically implemented properties is pretty clear:

> Automatically implemented
>   (auto-implemented) properties automate
>   this pattern. More specifically,
>   non-abstract property declarations are
>   allowed to have semicolon accessor
>   bodies. Both accessors must be present
>   and both must have semicolon bodies,
>   but they can have different
>   accessibility modifiers. When a
>   property is specified like this, a
>   backing field will automatically be
>   generated for the property, and the
>   accessors will be implemented to read
>   from and write to that backing field.
>   The name of the backing field is
>   compiler generated and inaccessible to
>   the user.

In other words, they can only have "`get;`" and "`set;`", with the possibility of access modifiers.

Answer (score 4):

No you        can't, because you don't have access to private field that generated for that property

Answer (score 4):

A quick Google search on "inotifypropertychanged auto properties" will lead you to several blog posts and articles on the subject. Here's one:

[INotifyPropertyChanged auto wiring or how to get rid of redundant code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38865/INotifyPropertyChanged-auto-wiring-or-how-to-get-rid-of-redundant-code.aspx)

Comment: While I can see that this will work, it actually looks messier than using backing-store variables

Comment: benPearce: An automatic property is for when you don't want to write any other code in the setter or getter. If you do (like notifying of property changes) then you need to write it. I don't agree with the PostSharp approach, but it's certainly a solution of sorts. I'm quite comfortable with code that manually writes out the variables.

Comment: silky: I agree with you on the Postsharp, while it is a solution I am not particularly keen on it.

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked of the Microsoft team behind C# 3.0 and they did say they would think about it, have a read [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=348849).

In the comments you will find more information, including why it's a bad idea if you need more control, as well as ways to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some AOP framework like [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.org/).

But it can reduce performance and build time.

Comment: Looks like Postsharp 2.0 does exactly this - http://www.postsharp.org/blog/introducing-postsharp-20-1-notifypropertychanged

Answer (score 1):

Since I asked this question this problem has actually been solved as an attribute and build task:
https://github.com/demigor/kindofmagic

Answer (score 0):

This behavior can be done with a proxy factory type generator. I already done that in my development Framework. If you use System.Reflection.Emit you can create a type proxier.
Consider below example:

```
var a = Proxier<InputType>.CreateInstance(new object[] { }); // object arrays are for different constructors
a.PropertyAccessed += ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The Fody add-in [PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) does this. Just like [KindOfMagic](https://github.com/demigor/kindofmagic), Fody uses Mono.Cecil to modify the IL of .net assemblies at compile time. The following example is listed in the PropertyChanged documentation:

**You write:**

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class Person 
{        
    public string GivenNames { get; set; }
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", GivenNames, FamilyName);
        }
    }
}
```

**What gets compiled:**

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    string givenNames;
    public string GivenNames
    {
        get { return givenNames; }
        set
        {
            if (value != givenNames)
            {
                givenNames = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("GivenNames");
                OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
            }
        }
    }

    string familyName;
    public string FamilyName
    {
        get { return familyName; }
        set 
        {
            if (value != familyName)
            {
                familyName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FamilyName");
                OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
            }
        }
    }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", GivenNames, FamilyName);
        }
    }

    public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
        if (propertyChanged != null)
        {
            propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

The [wiki](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged/wiki) includes some more advanced examples.

It is available using NuGet:

```
PM> Install-Package PropertyChanged.Fody
```